# Program crashes on trying to access the key that does not exist in map

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am doing a simple program that tries to fetch a non-existent key-value pair in the map. But when I run the code, I get a runtime error saying  `==8406==WARNING: AddressSanitizer failed to allocate 0x7ffe7f82c881 bytes
==8406==AddressSanitizer's allocator is terminating the process instead of returning 0
==8406==If you don't like this behavior set allocator_may_return_null=1`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    typedef std::map<std::string,int> mymap;
    mymap cnt;

    cnt["a"]=10;

    auto f = first.find("asdasd");
    std::cout << f->second;
    return 0;
}
```

at line where I do `f->second`. How could I handle the case where the key does not exist in the map?

Comment: "How could I handle the case where the key does not exist in the map" - Simple. Just check for `map::end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) member function of `std::map` specializations returns a past-the-end iterator if the key does not exist.

So you need to compare to the container's `end()`:

```
 auto f = cnt.find("asdasd");
 if (f != cnt.end()) {
     std::cout << f->second;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean

```
auto f = cnt.find("asdasd");
```

you need to check if the key that you looked for actually exists

```
if (f != cnt.end())
    std::cout << f->second;
```

Otherwise you are dereferencing an invalid location, and that's UB.